# A reference for converting assembly 'shl', 'OR', 'AND', 'SHR' operations into C?

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering, att

I'm to convert the following AT&T x86 assembly into C:

```
  movl 8(%ebp), %edx
  movl $0, %eax
  movl $0, %ecx
  jmp .L2
.L1
  shll $1, %eax
  movl %edx, %ebx
  andl $1, %ebx
  orl %ebx, %eax
  shrl $1, %edx
  addl $1, %ecx
.L2
  cmpl $32, %ecx
  jl   .L1
  leave
```

But must adhere to the following skeleton code:

```
int f(unsigned int x) {
    int val = 0, i = 0;
    while(________) {
        val = ________________;
        x = ________________;
        i++;
    }
    return val;
}
```

I can tell that the snippet

```
.L2
  cmpl $32, %ecx
  jl   .L1
```

can be interpreted as `while(i<32)`. I also know that `x` is stored in `%edx`, `val` in `%eax`, and `i` in `%ecx`. However, I'm having a hard time converting the assembly within the `while`/`.L1` loop into condensed high-level language that fits into the provided skeleton code. For example, can `shll`, `shrl`, `orl`, and `andl` simply be written using their direct C equivalents (`<<`,`>>`,`|`,`&`), or is there some more nuance to it?

Is there a standardized guide/"cheat sheet" for Assembly-to-C conversions?

I understand assembly to high-level conversion is not always clear-cut, but there are certainly patterns in assembly code that can be consistently interpreted as certain C operations.

Comment: Shifts are not *necessarily* 'bitwise operators. A well-established use is `x<<1` to stand for "multiply by 2". A C compiler might even translate an explicit multiplication by a power of 2 into a shift.

Comment: [This playground](https://godbolt.org/) may help.

Comment: The answer to [SO: Is there a complete x86 assembly language reference that uses AT&T syntax? (closed)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1776587/7478597) mentions [x86 Assembly Language Reference Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5477/817-5477.pdf).

Comment: @usr2564301 The 'bitwise operators' is a de facto standard name for the operators `| & ^ << >> ~` (and their compound assignment versions). No matter how they are used by the program.

Comment: "Is there a standardized guide/"cheat sheet" for Assembly-to-C conversions?" Hardly. The usual is the opposite way. :-)

Comment: I see you are asking many questions about decompiling. Are you implementing something like IDA's Hex-Rays? If so, take a look at Avast's RetDec decompiler, which is opensource.

Comment: @arrowd Yes, I should start learning to use IDA, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Scheff Thanks, that should prove quite helpful.

Comment: @usr2564301 - That's the exact sort of information I was looking for, thanks. I'm sure there's more similar hints on interpreting assembly code out there..

Comment: Why do you keep asking and deleting questions on the same subject?

Comment: I’d be surprised if you had evidence to back that statement. I wrote 1 question about assembly last week and deleted that after it was downvoted and I was told the question was unconventional (“weird”). That’s the only deleting I have done recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while (i < 32) { val = (val << 1) | (x & 1); x = x >> 1; i++; }` except val and the return value should be unsigned and they aren't in your template. The function returns the bits in x reversed.

The actual answer to your question is more complicated and is pretty much: no there is no such guide and it can't exist because compilation loses information and you can't recreate that lost information from assembler. But you can often make a good educated guess.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, can shll, shrl, orl, and andl simply be written using
>   their direct C equivalents (<<,>>,|,&), or is there some more nuance
>   to it?

they can. Let's examine the loop body step-by-step:

```
  shll $1, %eax    // shift left eax by 1, same as "eax<<1" or even "eax*=2"
  movl %edx, %ebx
  andl $1, %ebx    // ebx &= 1
  orl %ebx, %eax   // eax |= ebx
  shrl $1, %edx    // shift right edx by 1, same as "edx>>1" = "edx/=2"
```

gets us to

```
  %eax *=2
  %ebx = %edx        
  %ebx = %ebx & 1       
  %eax |= %ebx     
  %edx /= 2
```

ABI tells us (`8(%ebp), %edx`) that %edx is x, and %eax (return value) is val:

```
  val *=2
  %ebx = x           // a
  %ebx = %ebx & 1    // b
  val |= %ebx        // c
  x /= 2
```

combine a,b,c: #2 insert a into b:

```
  val *=2
  %ebx = (x & 1)  // b
  val |= %ebx     // c
  x /= 2
```

combine a,b,c: #2 insert b into c:

```
  val *=2
  val |= (x & 1)
  x /= 2
```

final step: combine both 'val =' into one

```
  val = 2*val | (x & 1)
  x /= 2
```

Comment: Excellent explanation. Quite easy to understand now! I didn't realize it was that simple. Feel free to ignore this next question, but I'm now asked to "Describe in English what function f computes:" and was wondering if you happened to immediately recognize what the function was doing in layman's terms.

Comment: left shifting one register 32 times, while right shifting the other. My guess is this function reverses the order of x's bits